# Is there a way to "count" elements that haven't rendered on the webpage?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently working on a chrome extension and I need to count the total number of books in a library. However, only half are counted in the array due to the other half not rendering until scroll down. I tried "MutationObserver", however, the count only shows once the changes are made (when I scroll down). I need the count to be displayed upon load.

```
// Variables
let list = document.querySelectorAll("ul > li");
let mlist = document.querySelector("ul");
let numBooks = [];

// Push books to array
for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  numBooks.push(i + 1);
}

// Observe changes
const observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
    if (mutation.addedNodes.length) {
      // Create Element: Book Count
      let url = "myurl";
      let nBooks = numBooks.length / 10;
      let nChanges = mutation.addedNodes.length - 1;
      if (url == window.location.href) {
        let el = document.createElement("span");
        el.innerHTML = nBooks + nChanges;

        let par = document.getElementsByTagName("h2")[0];
        par.appendChild(el);
      }
    }
  });
});
observer.observe(mlist, {
  childList: true,
});
```

Comment: There is no way anyone can be of help with the information that you have provided. However, I can tell you that if the books are loaded from server on scroll, obviously you can't count what you don't have. You have to ask to the server how many books there are.

Comment: I'm assuming the list is virtual, and loads on scroll, so unfortunately there is no way of getting this info, unless the website exposes the count somewhere else.